# Where are the tests for core CPython's C extension modules?

Tags: python, cpython, python-c-extension

In core CPython's source tree (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/), I cannot find the tests for the core C extension modules.

For example, where is the corresponding test file for `/Modules/_heapqmodule.c`?

(Note: I do see that there are tests at `/Lib/test/`, but those appear to be just for the Python stdlib modules that are written in Python.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in the `/Lib/test` directory (same for extension modules)

For example, test for `heapq` module is in http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/test/test_heapq.py

Comment: Actually, test_heapq.py is the test for the Python version heapq.py, not the C version _heapqmodule.c.

Comment: @coffee-grinder, It tests both Python version, C version.

Comment: @coffee-grinder: No, it's definitely testing the C version too. Look at all the `c_heapq` stuff in there.